# Kubernetes one service multiple deployments. Pros and cons?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195896/how-do-i-get-one-pod-to-network-to-another-pod-in-kubernetes-simple) the accepted answer shows how to have multiple deployments in a single service so they can talk to each other using their internal loadbalancer ports. What are the pros and cons? My guesses:

Pros:

- Easier to deploy?
- Easier communication between pods (no need for ingress)?
- Is there any added security since the backend could be accesses only from within the cluster?

Cons:

- You have to deploy all of the connected pods every time (not a
  microservice architecture)?

Comment: Your question is pretty much opinion based. I would highly suggest you to raise this topic in the original question instead of creating a new question for it. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

The only common reason to have multiple deployments in one service is for blue/green stuff, or *maybe* canary deploys (though usually that's done via a proxy with better control over the canary scaling factors). Beyond that, it comes up pretty rarely, sometimes maybe for integrating with Prometheus Operator's ServiceMonitor, or very niche tricks with in-place system rewrites.